# Rails Nested Resource Not Displaying Correct Index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, associations, rails-activerecord

So I have two models in Rails. However, when I visit the path /lectures/:id/users.json I do not get the users associated withe the particular lecture. I get ALL the users. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in this association/route but I'd appreciate a little guidance along the way! From what I can tell everything should be set up properly...

Lecture Associations

```
belongs_to :organization

  belongs_to :training_type
  has_many :training_histories
  has_many :users , through: :training_histories

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :training_histories
```

User association

```
 has_many :user_groups
  has_many :groups, through: :user_groups

  has_many :training_histories

  has_many :lectures
  has_many :lectures, through: :training_histories

  belongs_to :organization
```

Training History association

```
  belongs_to :lecture
  belongs_to :user # this could be any type of user

  delegate :training_type, to: :lecture

  has_many :attachments

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments
```

Routes

```
  resources :training_histories do
    member do
      get :next
    end
  end

  resources :lectures do
    resources :users

    collection do
      get :calendar
    end

  end
```

So far no matter how I change the association as long as Lectures have many Users and vice versa I can't get the particular Users for a Lecture using a resource call in Angular on the route /lectures/:id/users.json.

EDIT: When I rake routes I do get the route

```
lecture_users GET    /lectures/:lecture_id/users(.:format)          users#index
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First where is the code of your users controller index action, even you created the routes and association correctly still need to create the controller's proper code to get the correct result.

Second I noticed in the User model that you have declared the association with lectures twice which is not correct

```
has_many :training_histories

has_many :lectures
has_many :lectures, through: :training_histories
```

you should adjust it to be:

```
has_many :training_histories
has_many :lectures, through: :training_histories
```

Comment: took me a minute but i finally realized i had to alter my controller...doi! so this is totally correct.